# Laravel InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

Galera podem me ajudar com este erro...InvalidArgumentException in RouteRegistrar.php line 75: Attribute [when] does not exist.

Estou aprendendo laravel e este erro esta chato.

---

Segue Route(web)

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Validação CSRF
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post'));

// Visitante
Route::get('/',
        array(
            'as' => 'home', 
            'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'
            )
        );

Route::get('entrar', 'HomeController@getEntrar');
Route::post('entrar', 'HomeController@postEntrar');
Route::get('sair', 'HomeController@getSair');

// Verifica se o usuário está logado
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // Rota de artigos
    Route::controller('artigos', 'ArtigosController');
});

Index (/public)

<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

RouteRegistrar (Erro Apontado)

<?php

namespace Illuminate\Routing;

use Closure;
use BadMethodCallException;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class RouteRegistrar
{
    /**
     * The router instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router
     */
    protected $router;

    /**
     * The attributes to pass on to the router.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [];

    /**
     * The methods to dynamically pass through to the router.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $passthru = [
        'get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'options', 'any',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that can be set through this class.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $allowedAttributes = [
        'as', 'domain', 'middleware', 'name', 'namespace', 'prefix',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are aliased.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $aliases = [
        'name' => 'as',
    ];

    /**
     * Create a new route registrar instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value for a given attribute.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return $this
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function attribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (! in_array($key, $this->allowedAttributes)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Attribute [{$key}] does not exist.");
        }

        $this->attributes[array_get($this->aliases, $key, $key)] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Route a resource to a controller.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $controller
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function resource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->router->resource($name, $controller, $this->attributes + $options);
    }

    /**
     * Create a route group with shared attributes.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public function group($callback)
    {
        $this->router->group($this->attributes, $callback);
    }

    /**
     * Register a new route with the given verbs.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $methods
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  \Closure|array|string|null  $action
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    public function match($methods, $uri, $action = null)
    {
        return $this->router->match($methods, $uri, $this->compileAction($action));
    }

    /**
     * Register a new route with the router.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  \Closure|array|string|null  $action
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    protected function registerRoute($method, $uri, $action = null)
    {
        if (! is_array($action)) {
            $action = array_merge($this->attributes, $action ? ['uses' => $action] : []);
        }

        return $this->router->{$method}($uri, $this->compileAction($action));
    }

    /**
     * Compile the action into an array including the attributes.
     *
     * @param  \Closure|array|string|null  $action
     * @return array
     */
    protected function compileAction($action)
    {
        if (is_null($action)) {
            return $this->attributes;
        }

        if (is_string($action) || $action instanceof Closure) {
            $action = ['uses' => $action];
        }

        return array_merge($this->attributes, $action);
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically handle calls into the route registrar.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route|$this
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (in_array($method, $this->passthru)) {
            return $this->registerRoute($method, ...$parameters);
        }

        if (in_array($method, $this->allowedAttributes)) {
            return $this->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [{$method}] does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Certifica-te que as tuas rotas/metodos(get, post) estão corretas

Comment: Coloque o código de onde o erro esta sendo apontado.

Comment: Tira o when da tua rota ‘*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prezado,

Você deve estar usando o Laravel numa versão diferente do tutorial que está seguindo.  O método `when` não está disponível na versão 5.4, por exemplo.

Veja esse link abaixo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481954/laravel-invalidargumentexception-in-routeregistrar-php-line-75